# anchor.pathname is undefined on Chrome and works fine on Firefox

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, axios

On a sample page from a file server like this

"https://s-docs-srv-01.myorg.net:8443/fileServer/viewer/xxxx/test-21q2/Standard-HTML/index.html"

when I run the code below it returns undefined on Chrome but returns value on Firefox.

```
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.setAttribute("href","https://testurl.com/testfolder/folder/file.html"); 
var m = {href:a.href, pathname: a.pathname} 
console.log(m);
```

On Chrome browser: `{href: undefined, pathname: undefined}`

On Firefox browser: `{ href: "https://testurl.com/testfolder/folder/file.html", pathname: "/testfolder/folder/file.html" }`

On a NORMAL web page (like `https://myserver.com/file.html`), the same code returns expected values as

```
{ href: "https://testurl.com/testfolder/folder/file.html", 
  pathname: "/testfolder/folder/file.html" }.
```

I am not sure if it is some configuration issue on a fileserver. The issue started when we first encountered `"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'charAt' of undefined"` from chrome console on axios library where the code is `pathname: "/" === o.pathname.charAt(0) ? o.pathname : "/" + o.pathname`

Any idea how to handle this?

Comment: Your snippet works fine for me in Chrome.

Comment: Yeah. But, on a page like this https://s-docs-srv-01.myorg.net:8443/fileServer/viewer/xxxx/test-21q2/Standard-HTML/index.html it doesn't. I couldn't share the actual URL as the access is denied outside vpn.

Comment: JavaScript executes in the browser, it shouldn't matter where it comes from. Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: You don't have any plugin activated? What is that page exactly? What does `document.baseURI` outputs from there? And `location`? What does `window.crossOriginIsolated` output?

Comment: No plugins activated on chrome. document.baseURI -- https://s-docs-srv-01.myorg.net:8443/fileServer/viewer/xxxx/test-21q2/Standard-HTML/index.html
window.crossOriginIsolated -- false....
location -- expected values like host, hostname, href, etc.,

Comment: The issue is when we create dynamic anchor tag and tries to read pathname from that..

Comment: Then... what does `document instanceof HTMLDocument` output? And `document.createElement("a") instanceof HTMLAnchorElement`? Anyway, for your case, you might want to use the URL API instead: `const m = new URL("https://testurl.com/testfolder/folder/file.html");`

Comment: `document instanceof HTMLDocument` and `document.createElement("a") instanceof HTMLAnchorElement` both returns `false`. I can't use URL API, as the issue happens at axios library code.

Comment: Ah great, so we found the problem: Chrome doesn't treat your document as an HTML document, but probably as an XML one? So <a> is not an HTMLAnchorElement and doesn't have its properties. Check the response's headers to find out why Chrome doesn't treat this as HTML (particularly the Content-Type one). Though that's still weird Firefox treats it differently...

Comment: Thanks @Kaiido. The document starts with `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` which causes this issue. Once we remove the page works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` at the start of the HTML document fixed this issue.
The page was not considered as HTML document and we found that by executing `document instanceof HTMLDocument`.